# remove based url from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that works fine but I want to make sure that when users type in a url and then click on the link it takes them to the url they typed.

The problem that I am having is that when users type in their url, based url is being appended to the url they typed. For example  if users type in espn.com they get fiddle.jshell.net/BMDKr/5/show/espn.com.   I just want espn.com.

Can someone please advise?

http://jsfiddle.net/BMDKr/6/

```
<input type="text" id="text"> <a href="#" id="link" target="_blank">Link</a>



 $(function () {
// When the input field changes value
$('#text').blur(function(){

    // Set the attribute 'href' of the link to the value of the input field
    $('#link').attr('href', $('#text').val());
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if http:// is in the url they entered, and if not, you want to prepend it before setting the href on the link. You can use a regular expression to check for http:// and https://. Here is a basic example:

```
var url = $('#text').val();
if (!url.match(/^https?:\/\//i)) {
    url = 'http://'+url;
}
```